# Keeping at least one item selected in a wxListBox

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a multiple selection wxListBox and I want to keep the condition that at least one of the items in the list is selected.  I tried having

```
def OnSelectDataSource(self, event):
    datasourcelist = xrc.XRCCTRL(self, "m_lstDataSource")
    if not event.IsSelection():
        if len(datasourcelist.GetSelections()) == 0:
            datasourcelist.Select(event.GetInt())
```

as the handler for the `wx.EVT_LISTBOX` event.  This works, but you can see the item be deselected and then reselected.  There's probably a better method that I don't know of.

The deselection seems to be happening on mouse press down, and the event doesn't get called until mouse press up (and then the item is reselected).

---

Based on the suggested solution, I now have it working, with

```
xrc.XRCCTRL(self, "m_lstDataSource").Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.CheckDataSelect)
```

in my `__init__` method and

```
def CheckDataSelect(self, event):
    lstctrl = xrc.XRCCTRL(self, "m_lstDataSource")
    pos = lstctrl.HitTest(event.GetPosition())
    if lstctrl.GetSelections() == (pos,):
        event.Skip(False)
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the mouse up event and do your check to see if this will make the selection go to no items. If so, call event.skip() to prevent further handlers from touching your selection.

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html#Skip

Comment: This worked, although I needed to hook the mouse down, not the mouse up event.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent changes being visible while in progress:

wxWindow::Freeze
virtual void Freeze()

Freezes the window or, in other words, prevents any updates from taking place on screen, the window is not redrawn at all. Thaw must be called to reenable window redrawing. Calls to these two functions may be nested.

This method is useful for visual appearance optimization (for example, it is a good idea to use it before doing many large text insertions in a row into a wxTextCtrl under wxGTK) but is not implemented on all platforms nor for all controls so it is mostly just a hint to wxWidgets and not a mandatory directive.

Comment: Putting `datasourcelist.Freeze()` and `datasourcelist.Thaw()` around the code in the body of my handler function doesn't stop the visible unselection and reselection.